# Java, sqlite3 since command line troubleshooting

Tags: java, sqlite

my name is Omar
i am following the instructions in this webpage https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm in order to compile a sample program of java conected with sqlite3.
sample program

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteJDBC {
  public static void main( String args[] ) {
      Connection c = null;

      try {
        // Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
      } catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
   }
}
```

i downloaded the sqlite connector sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar but according to the webpage above, i Added the address  of downloaded jar file sqlite-jdbc-(VERSION).jar in my class path(the same class path of mysql  address connector) and place the sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext just like mysql connector driver.
but i got bad results when i try to run it in command line

"No suitable driver found for jdbc: sqlite: test.db"

i run java -classpath ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" SQLiteJDBC with the sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar in the same folder in command line but i got bad results too.

"No suitable driver found for jdbc: sqlite: test.db"

Where sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar connector should be placed according to connect java and sqlite just as myql do?

anyhelp is appreciated
thank you in advance
Omar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download and use the newest SQLite driver 3.27.2.1 from this site: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/

I tried it with 3.7.2 and got the same error. But with 3.27.2.1 it works well.

Comment: Thank you very much, you help me a lot with your answer, now SQLite is working, thanks